# Why won't Gmail show my selected picture?

Tags: gmail

I just noticed that my picture does not appear next to my name in Gchat for some mysterious reason.

I have had the same picture uploaded for years, so I don't know when it disappeared. I have been trying to reset it, and going through all of the "upload picture" steps, and it appears to upload just fine. However, it doesn't show up for me or anyone else after it appears to upload fine. I still don't have a picture. Instead of a picture it shows nothing, just white space. When I hover over it, it says "add a picture." I then click on that and it takes me to the "add picture" menu, which I then use to add a picture. Then it doesn't show up.

I have tried to upload it on both a Lenovo Thinkpad I use for work (running Firefox) and my MacBook Air I use personally (running Safari). It works for neither.

Why won't it show up, and how do I get a Gmail picture again?

Comment: What does it show instead of the picture... (blurry screenshot)

Comment: @phwd It shows nothing, just white space. When I hover over it, it says "add a picture." I click on that and it takes me to the "add picture" menu, which I do, and then it doesn't show up.

Comment: The same thing happened to me, and Greg's answer didn't help. I did exactly that, and it didn't work. My picture used to show up just fine, I don't know what's going on.
I know, I know, sorry I didn't actually answer the question, but this is the only place where someone has asked this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting questions are off-topic. On the other hand, Google Chat app have changed a lot since 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if you have yourself saved as a contact. I had a similar issue with Gmail once they change their interface. I solved it by removing myself from the contact list.